# Highlight all Occurrences of String - Not Incrementing Properly

Tags: javascript, uiwebview

I'm using the function [here](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/), my trouble with it is that it when I'm searching across multiple paragraphs, the `var = MyApp_SearchResultCount` doesn't count up consecutively for some odd reason. When I run the script on one block of text, it works as I would have expected, but when searching across multiple paragraphs I get something like this:

```
<p>
text text [id=4]search string[/] text text text text [id=5]search string[/] text 
text text text [id=6]search string[/] text text
</p>
<p>
text text [id=3]search string[/] text text text text 
text text text text text
</p>
<p>
text text text text text text [id=1]search string[/] text 
text text text [id=2]search string[/] text text
</p>
```

Does anybody have any idea why this happens and how to remedy it?

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/circleb/c9qVj/)

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?

Comment: I'm sorry, somehow I missed your answer, that fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because it was iterating through the children in reverse... try this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3tPR/)

The part I changed was here (starting at line 32):

```
    } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
        if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
            $(element).contents().each( function() {
                MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(this,keyword);
            });
        }
    }
```